# Scamming explanation

Tags: phishing, scam

I've just received a scam SMS with that invite me to click on a link to check a delivery.
Since I was curious about where it could lead, I opened a VM and set up a VPN, then clicked on the link. After different redirects I ended up on Google. So I'm wondering about the aim of this scam SMS.

Here there the HTTP responses (I obscured the cookies):

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.16.1
Date: Fri, 23 Apr 2021 15:49:07 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 208
Connection: close
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Location: https://track.drerries.com/8d912287-1150-46dc-8dc5-999464f50468?af=39&no=30-35
Vary: Accept

<p>Found. Redirecting to <a href="https://track.drerries.com/8d912287-1150-46dc-8dc5-999464f50468?af=39&amp;no=30-35">https://track.drerries.com/8d912287-1150-46dc-8dc5-999464f50468?af=39&amp;no=30-35</a></p>


HTTP/1.1 200 
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 23 Apr 2021 15:49:27 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, pre-check=0, post-check=0
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: XXXXXX Expires=Sat, 24-Apr-2021 15:49:27 GMT; Domain=track.drerries.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly;SameSite=None
Set-Cookie: XXXXXX; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Sat, 23-Apr-2022 15:49:27 GMT; Domain=track.drerries.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly;SameSite=None
Content-Length: 359

<html><head><link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='https://track.drerries.com:443/redirect?target=BASE64aHR0cDovL2dvb2dsZS5jb20&ts=1619192967438&hash=ogrCi1dIa7dWRxmVYfvbI_C2LDRrEOdTgzbxKxsLjaA&rm=D'" /></head><body></body></html>

HTTP/1.1 200 
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 23 Apr 2021 15:49:36 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 229
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, pre-check=0, post-check=0
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache

<html><head><link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="/><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://google.com'" /></head><body></body></html>
```

Comment: it's setting tracking cookies...  it might just be adware.  That first redirect includes " http://google.com " base64 encoded.  So I guess it tells it where to end up.  The hash might be your phone# or e-mail.. something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without being able to see everything that is happening, what other links like this do is to show *you* Google (or some other benign site), but in passing through other sites, they attempt to compromise your browser and system to install cryptominers or ransomware.

I'd suggest putting it through a malware analysis sandbox, like [cuckoo.ee](https://cuckoo.ee/) and see what it *really* does.

I put one of these links through VirusTotal and Cuckoo [a couple of years ago](https://youtu.be/npmHc-NNvGI) to show the difference between a URL scan and sandbox analysis.

Comment: thanks for the resource - incidentally, I tried to run OP's url through cuckoo.ee and it got to the status of completed, with no additional information - maybe it didn't download anything? I wound up giving it to [urlscan.io](https://urlscan.io/result/92247f98-5708-4b39-95d1-b15067b65041/#transactions) and it confirmed OP's observations of a couple of hops winding up at google

Answer (score 3):

The Guid in the link suggests every SMS has a unique code. This could be an attempt to just gather information:

1. Send an SMS to 1 million random numbers, with a link.
2. Record the ones that clicked through.

Now you have a much smaller list of numbers that you know is a valid cell number **and** whose owner is potentially scammable in the future. This refined list of numbers is much more valuable to scammers.

Comment: You reminded me of this old classic: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0643427/?ref_=ttep_ep2 (Mathnet episode about some scammer sending horseracing predictions to people randomly, and keeping track of the ones where the horse won to write again)